# Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Maybe I have not formulated the task clearly enough. The problem is as follows (related to image processing): The propagation function given in the following form:

[image]

and the object wave function modulated by the specimen are given in the following form:

$$Ψ(x,y)=A(x,y)\exp[iφ(x,y)]$$

where

$$A(x,y)=\exp⁡[-L \sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}]$$
$$φ(x,y)=K\sqrt{a^2-(x^2+y^2)}+S$$
$L$, $K$, $S$ - some const parameters.

It is required to calculate the following ratio:

$$Ψ_p=\text{IFT}[\text{FT}[Ψ]\text{FT}[p]]$$
where $\text{FT}$ - two-dimensional Fourier transform, $\text{IFT}$ - inverse two-dimensional Fourier transform.

My calculations in mathematics:
I find Fourier transorm for the two-dimensional $\text{FT}[p]$.

```
FourierTransform[p[x,y],{x,y},{u,v},FourierParameters -> {0, -2*Pi}]
```

Solution is:

```
1.E^((0. + 1.55024*10^-9 I) u^2 + (0. + 1.55024*10^-9 I) v^2)
```

But, I can't find a solution for the $\text{FT}[Ψ]$. I tried to find solution as follows:

```
FourierTransform[Ψ[x,y],{x,y},{u,v},FourierParameters -> {0, -2*Pi}]
```

But there is still no find a solution. Have any idea?

Comment: `f(x_,y_)` should be `f[x_,y_]`. This doesn't resolve the problem, though. Turning to `HankelTransform` may be a choice.

Comment: The Fourier transform of `Exp[Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)]]*Exp[I Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)]]` does not exist in traditional math since the integral of `Exp[Sqrt[(x^2 + y^2)]]` over the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ diverges (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)). I think the one does not exist in sense of distributions too.

Comment: Up to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) (if I correctly understand the "Domain of definition" section) , its Hankel transform does not exist too.

Comment: @user64494 Yeah, the Fourier transform of `f` doesn't seem to exist, but `HankelTransform[Exp[r] Exp[I r], r, k]` gives `-(I/(2 (1 - (I k^2)/2)^(3/2)))` in _v11.3_ and _v12.1.2_ (Wolfram Cloud), not sure if it's a bug or certain special definition has been used…

Comment: @xzczd: It's interesting. However, `HankelTransform[Exp[r] Exp[I r], r, k, GenerateConditions -> True]`  returns the input  in 12.1.1.0 .

Comment: @АртурГригорьевичФедоров: Your edit is of low quality (a code should be framed by ``, e.g. `code`) and not described. In fact, this is a new question.

Comment: This time I've done it for you, but please put a bit effort in learning to format your post properly. You may start from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help . Then, what values do you choose for $a$, $L$,$K$, $S$?

Comment: All uses of the variables atr in terms of `x^2+y^2` so it would be sensible to reduce to one dimension.